# Fixed starting date but dynamic ending date in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date-range

I am working with a database that also has its build-in BI tool. My work involves the following stages:

Step 1: Write SQL query (let's suppose I extract two columns, date and average daily revenue)
Step 2: Use the retrieved data to create a visualization
Step 3: Add the visualization to the dashboard

I am writing the following query:

SELECT date, AVG(revenue) as revenue
From table1
Group by date;

I want the dashboard to be dynamic which needs the SQL query to be dynamic first. 
The starting date is fixed, Oct 1, 2019 for example, but the ending date should be dynamic i.e. it should capture the data after every one day so that the dashboard gets updated daily.

How should my SQL query look like to achieve this purpose?

Comment: MYSQL does not have a built in bi tool so what are you using?

Comment: its a software called KATO, it has MYSQL and provides BI capabilities as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_ADD` to add a day as `INTERVAL` to start date.

```
SELECT rev_date,AVG(revenue) 
FROM table1 
WHERE rev_date BETWEEN "2020-06-15" AND DATE_ADD("2020-06-15",INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY rev_date;
```

PS: Using DATE as column_name is not best practice,DATE being a datatype in MYSQL.